# Impute missing values with replication constraints in R

Tags: r, interpolation, missing-data, imputation, imputets

I'm analyzing a long-term animal mark-recapture dataset, in which captured individuals are assigned to 1 of 5 size classes at each capture. I need to create a matrix that interpolates between and beyond known values (i.e., years the animal was observed) AND includes constraints on how long an individual can remain in each size class.

Below are a five sample capture histories (CH; individual=row), spanning 20 years (columns). There are five numerically coded possible size classes (1=smallest). NAs are years the animal wasn't captured (treated here as missing values).

Individuals can be observed for the first time in any size class (e.g. row 1 vs row 3), and we may recapture individuals that skipped over a size class (e.g., row 2).

```
CH <- rbind(c(NA,NA,1,2,rep(NA,7),3,rep(NA,8)),
            c(1,rep(NA,9),3,NA,NA,3,rep(NA,6)),
            c(rep(NA,10),4,NA,NA,5,rep(NA,6)),
            c(3,rep(NA,17),5,NA),
            c(rep(NA,7),2,rep(NA,8),4,rep(NA,3)))

CH

> CH
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]   NA   NA    1    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[2,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA     3    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA     4    NA    NA     5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[4,]    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     5    NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    2   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     4    NA    NA    NA
```

I've figured out how to interpolate the values with no constraints using the na.interpolation() function in the imputeTS package, shown below:

```
#ImputeTS missing values (with NO constraints, not ideal)
library(imputeTS)
ms.init.z  <- function(ms, notseen){
  state <- ms   # capture history called state
  for(i in 1:dim(state)[1]){ #Do this for every row/individual
    if(any(!is.na(state[i,1:dim(state)[2]-1]))){    #If any are not NA     through the 2nd to last occs'n
  state[i,dim(state)[2]] <- max(state[i,],na.rm=TRUE) #Apply max state value for that individual to final year
  #populate last column as as.interpolation needs at least two values
  state[i,] <- ceiling(na.interpolation(state[i,])) # interpolate
} #if

m <- min(which(!is.na(ms[i,])))   #identify the first occasion not NA
state[i,1:(m-1)] <- NA                #Replace before and on first occasion with NA  
  } #i
  return(state)
} #function
CH.X <- ms.init.z(CH,NA)

> CH.X
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]   NA   NA    1    2    3    3    3    3    3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
[2,]   NA    2    2    2    2    2    3    3    3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA     4     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
[4,]   NA    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    2    3     3     3     3     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
```

However, I would like to set constraints on how many years an individual can remain in each size class. I'm struggling to find a package that would allow me to implement customized constraints.

My "ideal" output is shown below. Note that there is more than one solution for most (all?) of each line, which is fine, as long as the number observations in each size class doesn't exceed the maximum (specified below).

```
#Desired constraints (maximum # of years in each size)
#Size class 1= 1 year max; 2= 7 yrs max; 3= 7 yrs max;
#4= 15 yrs max; 5= no limit

#Example Desired output
CH.cor <- rbind(c(NA,NA,1,rep(2,5),rep(3,6),rep(4,6)),
            c(1,rep(2,6),rep(3,7),rep(4,6)),
            c(rep(4,12),rep(5,8)),
            c(rep(3,3),rep(4,15),5,5),
            c(rep(NA,6),1,rep(2,7),rep(3,6)))

CH.cor 

> CH.cor
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
    [1,]   NA   NA    1    2    2    2    2    2    3     3     3     3     3     3     4     4     4     4     4     4
    [2,]    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    3    3     3     3     3     3     3     4     4     4     4     4     4
    [3,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4     4     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
    [4,]    3    3    3    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     5     5
    [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    2    2     2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

Any advice or help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't find a package, that offers you this functionally out of the box.

I have a tip using the imputeTS package:

If you want to maintain the NAs at the beginning when using **na.interpolation** you can use the following option:

```
library("imputeTS")
na.interpolation(x, yleft = NA)
```

This would save you 6 lines of code in your above example.

But for your problem you probably won't need this. Best option seems to me, to program a solution of your own. Since your requirements are very specific.